# UICollectionViewCell not displaying in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS and just trying to build a template view for future use.

I designed a view in `Main.Storyboard` with a `UICollectionView` - with several (hardcoded, I guess?) `UICollectionViewCells`. The `UICollectionView` displays when I test the app (background of that portion changes color), but I am not sure how to get the `UICollectionViewCells` to display.

All I have done so far is connect the view to the appropriate view controller, but I am very confused as to where to go from here.

My Main.Storyboard : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGeDW.jpg

If possible - is there a way to quickly add a function to trigger an alert when *any* `UICollectionViewCell` is clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to manually put an collectionViewCell like that. You might want to check this tutorials. For [swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1)  and [objC](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial)

Comment: @0yeoj This is simply all placeholder for now - is this really the only way?

Comment: You're on that right track(except for the cells). I just commented tutorials above (swift and objC), check them out. They are good and detailed.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView have very similar structure like UITableView.
So if you check its [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)  you will find what you need.In this case you need to implement this method:

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```